# Insert multiple rows to a table with 1 hit to the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, database-performance

By using LINQ, I added multiple rows in `dbContext` object. At `dbcontext.SaveChanges()`, sql profiler inserted every row individually as shown in the figure which shows that there are multiple hits to the database.

After a lot of google seaches I could not find the correct anwser. Can you give me a C# + Stored procedure way to save all the rows in a database hit.

[image: Multiple hits to the database]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[elegantcode.com](http://elegantcode.com/2012/01/26/sqlbulkcopy-for-generic-listt-useful-for-entity-framework-nhibernate/) has a fairly simple bulk insert method in "pure C#" that should do exactly what you're looking for.

> A common complaint of the Entity Framework is slow insert times for larger datasets... I ... roughed out a reusable generic version below, which produced 15k inserts in 2.4s or +- 6200 rows per second.